# How to enable/disable project services through API

Tags: azure, service, azure-devops, project

I am migrating from `TFS 2015` to `Azure DevOps`. The process of creating the target project and importing the old git repository can easily be done through the `Azure DevOps API`.

But each new project, either created manually or by API has always all services (`Boards`, `Pipelines`, `Test Lab`, ...) enabled. Is there a way to change the default setting of which services should be enabled on new projects? Or even better an API method to switch certain services on / off?

We have hunderets of projects and therefor it's not feasible to open each project in the browser, change to the project settings page and adjust the services.

I haven't found anything in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guy wrote a blog post on how to do this](https://www.teapotcoder.com/post/vsts-disable-features-services-api/)

This is an excerpt pulled from his post:

```
PATCH https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_apis/FeatureManagement/FeatureStates/host/project/{project-id}/{feature-id}?api-version='4.1-preview.1'
content-type: application/json

{"featureId":"{feature-id}","scope":{"settingScope":"project","userScoped":false},"state":0}
```

Replace account,project-id and feature-id as appropriate. Here are the feature id’s I know of.

```
ms.vss-build.pipelines  [Azure Pipelines]
ms.vss-test-web.test [Test Plans]
ms.vss-work.agile [Azure Boards]
ms.vss-code.version-control [Azure Repos]
ms.feed.feed [Azure Artifacts]
```

It looks like [turning a service off really just means hiding it from the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-services?view=azure-devops).

Edit: [it looks like the .net SDK has built in support for this as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.services.extensionmanagement.webapi.featuremanagement?view=azure-devops-dotnet)

Comment: This answer seems to be for TFS / Visual Studio and not for Azure DevOps as requested ... ?

Comment: This is for azure devops.

Comment: Azure Artifacts is `ms.azure-artifacts.feature`